# JUnit 5 Mockito Stubbing Referenced Method and Verifying it was Called

Tags: mockito, junit5

I'm working with JUnit5 and their `ParameterizedTest` feature.  How do I work with method references as part of the data source?

Example:

```
public enum Status {
  APPROVE, DECLINE
}

@Mock
public MockService mockService;

// Normal Test
@Test
void testApprove() {
  Mockito.doReturn(null)
    .when(mockService)
    .approveCall();

  Mockito.verify(mockService).approveCall();
}

// Parameterized Test
Map<Status, Supplier<?>> mockMap = Map.ofEntries(  // Java 9 method
  Map.entry(APPROVE, mockService::approveCall),
  Map.entry(DECLINE, mockService::declineCall)
);

@ParameterizedTest
@EnumSource(Status.class)
void test(Status status) {
  Supplier<?> supplier = mockMap.get(status);

  ??
}
```

I want my second test to do the same thing as my first test, but also covering the `DECLINE` value. How do I parameterize the mock method reference?

Comment: I am missing the MockService class, but as MockService is not a functional interface this will not compile complaining "Object is not a functional interface".

Comment: @Mock fields don't need to be functional interface. The Supplier is the functional interface the method reference is implementing.

Comment: @HaimRaman it compiles when approveCall and declineCall return something other than void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it with a few functional/lambda tricks.

```
public class MyTest {
    public enum Status {
        APPROVE, DECLINE
    }

    @Mock
    public MockService mockService;


    // Parameterized Test
    Map<Status, MockitoVerifier> mockMap = Map.ofEntries(  // Java 9 method
            Map.entry(Status.APPROVE, () -> Mockito.verify(mockService).approveCall()),
            Map.entry(Status.DECLINE, () -> Mockito.verify(mockService).declineCall())
    );

    @ParameterizedTest
    @EnumSource(Status.class)
    void test(Status status) {
        MockitoVerifier<?> verifier = mockMap.get(status);
        verifier.verify();
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface MockitoVerifier<T> {
        T verify();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. However, you did not cover stubbing the mock. This is producing a lot of repetition of code which I wanted to avoid... I will accept this answer as a workaround, even though the actual answer is `No, Mockito does not support this`.